# how to make operator AND in JSTL if tag?

Tags: jsp, tags, jstl, jsp-tags

i want to make authentication from XML file in in JSP page, but i don't know how to make double conditions (login and password) in tag x:if , please help me !

Comment: can you provide your effort with code?

Comment: You shouldn't *be* doing this kind of authentication in a JSP page at all. You should be using Container Managed Authentication; you should have your passwords hashed in a database; and you, or rather the container, should be querying the database to find if there is such a username/password pair. Nowhere should you be comparing passwords in code.

Comment: agree with @EJP, but if this is for testing purposes or some research work, that should be fine.

Comment: yes it's just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Core JSTL**:

```
<c:if test="${login eq 'test' and password eq 'test'}"/>
...
</c:if>
```

**XML JSTL**: (argument to select attribute should be a valid XPath syntax). Example below:

```
<c:set var="xmltext">
  <user>
    <username>test</username>
    <password>test</password>
  </user>
</c:set>

<x:parse xml="${xmltext}" var="output"/>

<x:if select="$output//username = 'test' and $output//password= 'test'">
   Successfully logged in.
</x:if>
```

The above example, parses the input XML. It then will test the values of elements `username` and `password` using `<x:if>`

Comment: it does not work because there is no attribute name test in this tag ?

Comment: Are you sure you are working with JSTL? test is a valid attribute of if tag.
See documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/

Comment: here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/ : if has 3 attributes : var , select and scope

Comment: i see. i thought it was core jstl you are using. let me do bit of research on this

Comment: very Good , that i'm looking for tank you @Ish

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem kindly accept this post as the answer. Thanks